# Asp.Net Core Identity check IsAdmin

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have two roles Admin and User in my Asp.Net Core MVC application. I would like to make a simple check that the user is an administrator. To do this, I created this method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult IsAdmin() => Ok();
```

The client JavaScript code calls like this:

```
async function isAdminAsync() {
    let response = await fetch('/Account/IsAdmin');
    if (response.ok) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it didn't work! When a user with the "User" role makes a request to the action method of the **IsAdmin** controller, the MVC infrastructure redirected to

```
https://localhost:7008/Account/AccessDenied?returnUrl=%2FAccount%2FIsAdmin
```

and I get a 200 response on the client (as a result, I have true). Although I'm waiting for 401 (I expect false). How can this be fixed?

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments implemented as follows:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult IsAdmin() => Ok(new object { });

async function isAdminAsync() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('/Account/IsAdmin');
        if (response.ok) {
            await response.json();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check User on HttpContext to see if in the role.  Your method will always return login url if the user is not in that role.  You can search for "check user role in mvc" in google and will find lots of examples.

Comment: Yes, specifically for IsAdmin, I know how to do as you say, thanks. The question can be asked more generally: instead of IsAdmin there can be a method that returns data. How to use JS fetch to get not a login page or a View that access is denied, but either 401 or the data itself.

Comment: Action result can respond as JSON so you can can respond with Json from the action as required.

Comment: JSON data will be received provided that the user belongs to the Admin role. If this is not the case, then instead of JSON data, fetch gets a text view of the login's HTML page. Although a 401 response code is expected.

Comment: You can return a Forbidden result as JSON.  Because you will always call this method using javascirpt (I am guessing) you can return a 401 along with the url to login page as a custom JSON object.